# Facebook Graph API. How to get likes for comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I need to get ids of people who liked some comment.

For example, I have the post with id 246595548763188_464132103676197 , and this post has comment with id 464146663674741.

Then, I use Graph Api Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

*Permissions:* user_groups

*Graph API URL:* https://graph.facebook.com/464146663674741

*Result:*

```
{
  "id": "464146663674741", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Rostyslav Paranko", 
    "id": "100001288191932"
  }, 
  "message": "Українську мову доконають пуристи.", 
  "can_remove": false, 
  "created_time": "2013-06-03T19:10:57+0000", 
  "like_count": 8, 
  "user_likes": false
}
```

As you can see, `like_count` has value `8`, but I can't see ***people who liked this comment*** (with ids and names). `https://graph.facebook.com/464146663674741/likes` returns empty array.

So, is it possible to get comment's likes using Graph API (or, maybe, FQL Query)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the comment ID and make this Graph API request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/COMMENT_ID?fields=likes
```

The comment ID is in fact the concatenation of:

- the POST_ID (`246595548763188_464132103676197`),
- the COMMENT_ID (`464146663674741`),

which would give in your case: `246595548763188_464132103676197_464146663674741`.

So, this should work:

[`graph.facebook.com/246595548763188_464132103676197_464146663674741?fields=likes`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=246595548763188_464132103676197_464146663674741%3Ffields%3Dlikes)

Comment: As I said in my question, it returns empty array. I tried to turn on all possible permissions, but it didn't help.

Comment: We were using the wrong comment ID. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: This does not work for comments in [Facebook comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments). Any ideas? e.g.: http://graph.facebook.com/1413368805547567_1587264078158038_1587264078158038?fields=likes,like_count