# How to get likes of a comment in Facebook comments plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to get a list of users who liked a post in [Facebook comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments). For example:

http://graph.facebook.com/1413368805547567_1587264078158038_1587264078158038?fields=likes,like_count

which does not show the list of users even the `likes` field is specified.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955653/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-likes-for-comment) provided here does work for comments in groups, News Feed, etc but not for comments in the comments plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment ID provided in the "date hyperlink" (located at bottom right of a comment), e.g.: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/?fb_comment_id=fbc_1413368805547567_1587264078158038_1587264078158038, is wrong.

The correct comment ID in the example above should be `1413368805547567_1587264078158038` with the last part of "_XXXX..." removed.

That makes http://graph.facebook.com/1413368805547567_1587264078158038?fields=likes,like_count work as expected.